# Fortify Error: Unexpected Exception During Dataflow Analysis

Tags: java, fortify

I've recently been getting a similar set of errors with each attempt to use HP Fortify to scan our code:

```
[error]: Unexpected exception during dataflow analysis (file [Java Class File])
```

Repeated 9 times (including the above) for different Java classes in our project, followed by the following message:

```
[warning]: Some errors or warnings were suppressed.  Check the results file for a full listing of all warnings and errors.
```

This leads me to believe that there are yet *more* errors that I'm not seeing - but I don't know wher to find these additional errors, and any hints they may have about the source of the error we're getting in our scan.

How can I see an extended list of the errors being reported in my HP Fortify Scan, and what can I do to resolve these scan errors?

Answer (score 1):

To see the full errors and diagnostic information, use `-debug-verbose` as a command line argument.